# How can I draw continuous curves in flot charts?

Tags: flot, curve, continuous

I'm trying to make a line chart in flot and I was wondering if it's possible to represent continuous lines. I mean curves such as y=ax^2+bx+c, or sin(x).

I already know that I can make a "for" sentence and draw the curve as a composure of short segments, but I would like to avoid this way.

Is it possible? How could I make it? Thnx guys!

Comment: `flot` does not provide this ability.  I'd imagine that even plotting programs which do accept functions, at their core, plot it with a good old fashioned for loop and evaluating the function.

Comment: ok Mark, that's what I thought and it really works. Thnx!

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712172/2610249) for an example.