# How to render f(x) = 1/x with flot.js?

Tags: function, math, flot

I am considering use flot.js to render the  function f(x) = 1/x for 3 cases:

```
f(x) = 1/n  , 
f(x) = n/x , and 
f(x) = 1/x +n
```

I would like to have the student able to change n to see what happens so I will need to refresh the graph as well.

I have no clue how to render the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill an array with e.g. 100 values and then use that array to plot the graph. Something like this:

```
var f1array = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    f1array.push([0.1 * i, 1 / (0.1 * i)]);
}
$.plot('#placeholderdiv', [f1array]);
```

Use this as a starting point and come back if you have further questions.

Edit: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/U7c4C/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had not seen your answer until now.

Comment: That happens automatically if you have values in at least two opposing ones. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7c4C/1/).